# App Engine deploy issue (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9]

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I just tried redeploying the same project I already had deployed. I added a few static files, nothing else, and tested it locally it works perfectly. Though, when deploying I get an error:
Beginning deployment of service [default]...

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 0 files to Google Cloud Storage                ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build XXX-5ad7883fea49 status: FAILURE
Build error details: Build error details not available.
Full build logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/XXX-5ad7883fea49?project=XXX
```

I tested all there was on the internet I could find, I couldn't find a fix for the Error #9. I checked the logs, they're not any more informative, at least not to me:

```
Starting Step #4 - "analyzer"
Step #4 - "analyzer": Already have image (with digest): us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/nodejs12/builder:nodejs12_20210105_12_20_1_RC00
Step #4 - "analyzer": ERROR: failed to initialize cache: failed to create image cache: accessing cache image "us.gcr.io/[project name]/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/default/buildpack-cache:9aef878d-ea0b-4e41-9b60-13bfd4b6a332": connect to repo store 'us.gcr.io/[project name]/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/default/buildpack-cache:9aef878d-ea0b-4e41-9b60-13bfd4b6a332': GET https://us.gcr.io/v2/[project name]/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/default/buildpack-cache/manifests/9aef878d-ea0b-4e41-9b60-13bfd4b6a332: DENIED: Permission denied for "9aef878d-ea0b-4e41-9b60-13bfd4b6a332" from request "/v2/[project name]/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/default/buildpack-cache/manifests/9aef878d-ea0b-4e41-9b60-13bfd4b6a332". 
Finished Step #4 - "analyzer"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 4 "us.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/nodejs12/builder:nodejs12_20210105_12_20_1_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

I don't understand what image it's talking about, though I tried deleting the whole App Engine to read it back to fix this and I think I cannot do that without losing my project-id, which is not something I want to do.

I am using NodeJS12 and ExpressJS, nothing else. app.yaml is below:

```
# [START gae_quickstart_yaml]
runtime: nodejs12
# [END gae_quickstart_yaml]
```

Any ideas what else I could do? There's so little in this project that I am basically stuck at the point of what else is there to cut to test if it's the issue. I checked if the issue persists in the Google Cloud Shell, it does, so I guess it's not a local bug.

Comment: Is your package.json also in nodejs12? do you have depencies with warning when you perform a npm install?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere thank you for commenting. My package.json has no information set regarding node.js version. There's a single dependency: `"express": "^4.17.1"`. I have no issues running `npm install`.

Comment: Make sure that the Cloud SDK is up to date to [it's latest version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes) (running `gcloud components  update` and try to deploy your application using `gcloud app deploy --no-cache`. Also make sure you are not exceeding any of the limits related to quotas (e.g. single static data file exceeding 32 MB or number of daily deployments) as explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas). Hope this helps.

Comment: @DanielOcando thank you for your comment. I ran components update before posting the question it had absolutely no effect on the result. The total size of all files in the project is 20.2MB. Just tried doing the `--no-cache` command, got the same result with error response [9].

Comment: Going through the error message shared I see you have a permissions denied error. Create a new bucket, make sure that both your App Engine and Cloud Build service accounts have Storage Admin permissions to be able to write and read to the bucket and use both the --bucket and --no-cache flags on your gcloud app deploy command.

Comment: @Telion did the instructions provided by Daniel above regarding the use of a new staging bucket with proper `Storage Admin` permissions fixed the issue you were facing while deploying?

Comment: @DanielOcando Thank you! I tried another storage bucket first and assigned app engine's permissions to it as a bucket owner for `[project id]@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`. It finally went through. Then I tried the same for the original bucket that's automatically created by the app engine and it worked too. This is weird, why wouldn't app engine automatically assign correct permissions? I deleted all 3 buckets it created and tried deploying again, the issue persisted so I manually assigned app engine's worker permission and left it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki since it's based on the comments made by @DanielOcando

The error message hints on the issue being a issue with the permissions on the bucket.

In order to fix it you will can create a new bucket, make sure that both your App Engine and Cloud Build service accounts have Storage Admin permissions to be able to write and read to the bucket and use both the `--bucket` and `--no-cache` flags on your `gcloud app deploy` command.

As per why this occured in the first place, it's difficult to say without checking your project, so I would advise you to open a [private customer issue on Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491299&template=1161102), so that this can be determined by their Engineering Team.